# Is it possible to send variables back from PHP to AJAX after AJAX to PHP request?

Tags: php, ajax

I have an AJAX request that fetches some info from a SQL database in PHP.

The problem is, I need to send it back to AJAX in variables. Not to just echo it all out on screen.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please give a practical example why you'd need this

Comment: why not send it back as json?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder, Yes, I am.

Comment: what have you tried? Where do you found the problem? If you have the data send to php through Ajax, when you get the response from php you still have those variables with their values...

Comment: 1 word. Well, sort of 4. [JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the variable you want to send back to client.

```
echo json_encode( array('variable' => 'your value' ) );
```

The client will receive the data through a callback when the request is completed. Without more clarification on specifics that's all i can offer, with some more details i can provide code samples depending on whether you're using a JavaScript library such as jQuery or doing a raw XHR request.

Edit: so in jquery to retrieve the variable above you would do the following.

```
$.getJSON('yourfile.php', function(data){
      console.log( data.variable ); 
});
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. You know where you've written "function(data)" is that ("data") a function I'm supposed to write up myself? If so, what's supposed to be in it. So far, I've tried the code and it doesn't do anything. it also stops executing any code beyond the JQuery bit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you'll want to build a php array and use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to dump the array out as your response. Then in JS you can use the resutling JSON text to form an object.

**ajaxpage.php**

```
$resultArray = buildArrayOfItems('Select * from products order by price');
//I usually have my sql records returned directly as an array.
//that's all buildArrayOfItems does

die(json_encode($resultArray));
```

The PHP should yield something like this

**results**

```
{[
    {
      "id" : "2643",
      "name" : "Leather Jacket",
      "price" : "249.99"
    },
    {
      "id" : "2645",
      "name" : "Suede Jacket",
      "price" : "289.99"
    },
    ...
]}
```

and your JS will look like this (if you're using jQuery)

**JS**

```
$.getJSON('ajaxPage.php', {'someVariable':'someValue'}, function(obj){
    console.log(obj.count); //will show number of resulting items
    console.log(obj[0].id); //will show id of first item (2643)
});
//If you do not use jQuery, you'll need to use eval() or something evil like that
//to convert the string to an object
```

Answer (score 0):

This site has a great example regarding what you're trying to achieve. http://ditio.net/2008/07/17/php-json-and-javascript-usage/

In short you'll want to use php's json_encode() to convert an array into a json compatible string and each that back to the client.

If  you're using jQuery then you'll need to dataType property of $.ajax()  to "json", from there you can interact directly with the response as a json object.

If you're using the standard XmlHttp.

```
var json = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always return something like:

```
echo "code you need to send back to AJAX &&& response text"
```

Then you can subdivide it into 2 variables with text.split("&&&").

Comment: What in the world ? That's a horrible way of doing it!

Comment: This is a bad, bad, BAD idea.