# How to return the executed query to $.ajax data from php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have code which posts a variable to php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.sub_menu a').click(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text();  
        //console.log("you clicked"+txt);
            $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'thegamer.php',
        data: {send_txt: txt},
        success: function( data ){
        //now echo the data where you want
        // for example
        //$('#result').html( data );
        // or you can see in on firebug
        console.log( 'Return:' + data );
            }               
     });
});
});
```

The php that gets the request:

```
   <?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
$q=$_REQUEST['send_txt'];

  //echo $q;

 $sql="select imgurl from images where family='shoes'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


include 'dbclose.php';
?>
```

How do I return the data back to the ajax request?

Comment: The PHP you posted should really not be returning **any** text, with the echo command commented out. I think you have some debug code in `dbconnect.php` as `resource=5` is normally displayed when you call `var_dump()` on a connection object. See this post for the right way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609356/is-it-possible-to-send-variables-back-from-php-to-ajax-after-ajax-to-php-request/8609421#8609421

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, I really suggest you learn more about Javascript, JQuery, AJAX and PHP before you attempt it. It looks like you have no clue how to go about this.

I'll point you in the right direction starting with W3 Schools (although definitely not the best resource but, it's a good start):

**[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)**

- [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp)
- [JQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp)
- [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)

Here's some more information about JQuery from their own [JQuery API Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

More specifically, the [$.ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

And here's how you [connect to a Mysql database using PHP](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/connect_mysql_database.php)

---

With that being said, this is a general example, using your information, of how you would go about doing an AJAX/server response. I post this so that you might learn something from this code, as it does specifically what you requested:

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#element').click(function() {
        //Get data to be sent to server
        //var sFamily = $("#family_search").text();
        //var sFamily = $(this).text();
        var sFamily = "family";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'thegamer.php',
            data: {family: sFamily },
            success: function(response){
                //Use response
                //alert("Server echo: "+response);
                $("#output_element").html(response);
            },
            error: function(msg){
                alert("Error: "+msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP file "thegamer.php"

```
<?php
    //Credentials
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password ="admin";
    $db = "dbo";

    //Connect
    $link = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);
    //Select database
    mysql_select_db($db, $link);

    //Assemble query
    $family = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['family'], $link);
    $query = "SELECT imgurl FROM images WHERE family='$family'";

    //Query database
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link);

    //Output result, send back to ajax as var 'response'
    echo "<table>";
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        //Fetch rows
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['imgurl']."</td></tr>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<tr><td>No results matching family \"$family\"</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    //mysql_free_result($result)
    //mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $arr[] = $row['your_column'];
}

echo json_encode($arr); // this json_encoded result can be obtained from data parameter of ajax success function

//and in ajax
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.sub_menu a').click(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text();  
        //console.log("you clicked"+txt);
            $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'thegamer.php',
        data: {send_txt: txt},
        success: function( data ){
        alert(data); // this will hold your $result value
        console.log( 'Return:' + data );
            }               
     });
});
});
```

Comment: Really? How can you `echo` a mysql resource?

Comment: yes it echos but a resource @shef r u here to humilitate us or give us an idea

Comment: He returns a json_encode of the fetched result.

Comment: so how to display the proper data

Comment: @sajid I am here, because I like to help others who show some effort at learning. Without you first learning the basics how can I talk code if you don't understand code...

Comment: @Sudhir please use code blocks, not `<pre>` tags to format your code properly.

Comment: @Sudhir What should be noted is that if you're going to return JSON data, you have to specify that in the $.ajax settings `dataType: 'json'`. Also, I doubt OP knows what JSON is, as he has little understanding of the AJAX concept to begin with. This will ultimately end up confusing him more than helping him.

Comment: @Sudhir Oh, and you're returning an object in the success function, so the only output you will see is object[Object]. Outputting an object can be done using `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense, but you are asking "how return something back to ajax?" Well you can simply use `echo` keyword to return data back to client.

Comment: i did but the same is printed there resource=5